# why don't set the placeholder attribute for contact field?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-hooks, form-api

this is my code that use in `hook_form_alter` function for set the placeholder attribute:

```
        if ($form_id == 'contact_site_form') {
            $form['name']['#title'] = t('name/family name');
            $form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Enter your name');
        }
```

why don't set the placeholder attribute for contact field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line to code and the problem was solved:

```
 $form['name']['#default_value'] ='';
```

Edited code is:

```
if ($form_id == 'contact_site_form') {
    $form['name']['#title'] = t('name/family name');
    $form['name']['#default_value'] ='';
    $form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Enter your name');
}
```